# EF Core 7 - Map a table in 2 lists

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

```
public class Customer
{
    public List<Appointment>? Appointments { get; set; }
    public List<Appointment>? History { get; set; }
}
```

```
    public class Appointment
    {
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

I have those 2 classes, and my question is: how can I  manually configure the relationship in the OnModelCreating, based on the date? My desire would be to have a table of customers which they can have multiple raws in the appointment table, from the DB point of view; from the entity point of view, I want customer.Appointments to contain appointments in the future and in the customer.History appointments from the past, based on the Date from the Appointment. (Basically I don't want to have only one list and filter each time based on a date and somehow I need to tell EF on migration that I'm talking about only one table even if I have 2 lists)

If I don't map them at all I get: "Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Appointment.Customer' of type 'Customer'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core multiple navigation properties to same table with fluent api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060904/ef-core-multiple-navigation-properties-to-same-table-with-fluent-api)

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? What about [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) for storing historical data? [SQL Server temporal tables in EF Core 6.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've tried the answers from your URL, and it does not work. I get `Cannot create a relationship between 'Customer.Appointments' and 'Appointment.Customer' because a relationship already exists between 'Customer.History' and 'Appointment.Customer'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Appointment.Customer' first in 'OnModelCreating'.`

Comment: As DBMS I am using PostgreSQL